# Global object being modified when it shouldn't be

Tags: java, android

I've extended the `Application` class to allow me to store application wide objects. One of these objects is a `JSONObject` that's read in from a JSON file local to the app. The `EnvConfig` is a custom class I wrote that just returns that JSON config object. This `ExtendedBase` class makes it available to me globally.

My problem is that when I'm in my activity I do the following to get the config `JSONObject`. In it I grab a template `JSONObject(pageJSON)` in an `AsyncTask` and I modify it and use that as the body of a RESTful API call to retrieve a resource.

```
myApp = (ExtendedBase) getApplicationContext();
JSONConfig = myApp.getConfig();
JSONObject page = JSONConfig.getJSONObject("singlePages").getJSONObject(pageTitle);
JSONObject pageJSON = page.getJSONObject("json");
```

That works. I get the resource from the RESTful API and then from a custom class I do the same thing. Get the `pageJSON` from the globally available `getApplicationContext()`, MODIFY `pageJSON` in an async task, and make another RESTful API call to update the resource. Which works. BUT when I start the process over again (go back to the activity and try to make an API call to retrieve another resource by getting the `pageJSON` template object), it is somehow reflecting the changes I made when I made the update API call. The original, global `JSONObject` should not be changed at all. It's like I'm updating the globally available object and not creating new `JSONObjects` like I think it should be doing.

Anybody have a clue on how to remedy this?

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Application;

public class ExtendedBase extends Application {

    private EnvConfig envConfig;
    private JSONObject JSONConfig;
    public static Record record = null;
    public static Boolean hasSavedRecord = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        envConfig = new EnvConfig();
        JSONConfig = envConfig.getEnvConfig(this);
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public JSONObject getConfig() {
        return JSONConfig;
    }

    public void setRecord(Record mRecord){
        this.record = mRecord;
    }

    public Record getRecord(){
        return record;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class GlobalApplication extends Application {
     private JSONObject globalVariable;

```
 public JSONObject getGlobalInstance() {
         return globalVariable;
 }

 public void setGlobalInstance(JSONObject globalVariable) {
         this.globalVariable = globalVariable;
 }
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
         //reinitialize variable
 }
```

Setting Global Value in Your Activity

```
((GlobalApplication)getApplication()).setGlobalInstance(jsonObject);
```

getting like this

```
jsonObject=((GlobalApplication)getApplication()).getGlobalInstance();
```

}

Like wise you can store multiple Global value and retrieve in the same way.

**Don't forget to add Application to the manifest file**

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="package.GlobalApplication" >
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: in my activity when i do something like JSONObject JSONConfig = ((GlobalApplication)getApplication()).getGlobalInstance(); will i be working on the same global instance? or will i be making a copy? I would like to be making a copy so i can modify it in the activity and not affect the global object

Answer (score 0):

change `getConfig()`  as to get latest value without creating Application instance again :

```
public JSONObject getConfig() {

 JSONConfig = envConfig.getEnvConfig(this);//call here instead of inside onCreate()
 return JSONConfig;
}
```

and also make sure you are not making any API call inside `EnvConfig` class constructor.

Comment: so in my activity when i do something like JSONObject JSONConfig = myApp.getConfig(); will i be working on the same global instance? or will i be making a copy? I would like to be making a copy so i can modify it in the activity and not affect the global object